# Searching for a key value in the list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list `l` containing multiples dictionaries `l = [ d1, d2,  ...., d100]`, where each dictionary is defined with keys `'id'`, `'address'`, `'price'`. 
Now, I want to take all dictionaries `d` from the list `l` for which value of key `'price'` is equal 50.  Is there a faster way to do this than using a for loop? This processing is already encapsualted within other for loop function, so I would prefer to not have two for loop if possible.
The skeleton of the function looks right now as:

```
for ... (external for loop):
    results = []
    for d in l:
        if d['price'] == 50:
           results.append(d)
```

Comment: There is nothing faster than looping (wel how you look can be slightly modified, but you still have to loop), since every item can have a price 50, so you need to inspect all dictionaries. The only way to optimize the *time complexity* further is if you know something of the *structure* of the data.

Comment: I assume `l` is different with each outer loop iteration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless you know something of the *structure* of the list (for instance ordered by price, or only three items can have such price), we can not make the algorithm faster than *O(n)* (linear time). So somehow we will have to loop.

## List comprehension

We can use list comprehension like for instance:

```
[d for d in l if d.get('price') == 50]
```

(this will also filter out dictionaries that do not have a price attribute).

## Pandas

We can also use pandas. Pandas is an efficient library for dataframes, that tends to outperform Python loops given the data is *huge*. In that case we can load the dictionaries in a datframe, perform filtering on it, and then retrieve a list of dictionaries. Note that these will be *different* dictionaries (i.e. other objects containing the same data). So the data is "copied".

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(l)
result = list(df[df.price == 50].T.to_dict().values())
```

So here we filter with `df.price == 50`. Note that behind the curtains there is however some loop involved to do the filtering.

This is also a more *declarative* approach: the code explains more *what* it is doing, instead of *how*. How pandas does the filtering is not much of your problem, and the syntax shows rather elegantly that you are filtering data.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Especially for the suggestion about Pandas - I changed the code and started using it and it turned out it is a great solution for my whole program!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
results = [d for d in l if d['price'] == 50]
```

This is algorithmically not different from your loop (it also must iterate the entire list), but the comprehension is optimized in C and therefore faster. Another option would be to make `results` a lazy iterator:

```
# generator expression
results = (d for d in l if d['price'] == 50)

# filter (not the most elegant/readable with lambda)
results = filter(lambda d: d['price'] == 50, l)
```

This will not iterate the `list` at all at declaration time. It will only do so when you iterate `results` (which you can do only once). This might help if you do not always or only partially need to iterate `results`.

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr - You can't go wrong with using a list comprehension

I explored the following methods:

1. Basic for-loop
2. List Comprehension with an if-comparison
3. Built-in filter function with lambda expression
4. List Comprehension over generator

These methods were explored in Python 2.7.12 and Python 3.5.2 (not the latest version). It seems that in Python 2 the best approach is method 4 and in python 3 the best approach is method 2 (at least for my version, which again is not the latest).

Here are the results for **Python 2.7.12**:

```
# 2.7.12
# [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
# Method 1 found 496 item in 0.382161 seconds. (basic for-loop)
# Method 2 found 496 item in 0.365456 seconds. (list comprehension)
# Method 3 found 496 item in 0.565614 seconds. (built in filter function)
# Method 4 found 496 item in 0.273335 seconds. (list comprehension over a generator expression)
```

Here are the results for **Python 3.5.2**:

```
# 3.5.2 
# [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
# Method 1 found 493 item in 0.500266 seconds. (basic for-loop)
# Method 2 found 493 item in 0.338361 seconds. (list comprehension)
# Method 3 found 493 item in 0.796027 seconds. (built in filter function)
# Method 4 found 493 item in 0.351668 seconds. (list comprehension over a generator expression)
```

Here is the code used to get results:

```
import time
import random
import sys

print(sys.version)

l = []
for i in range(10000):
    d = {'price': random.randint(40, 60), 'id': i}
    l.append(d)

#METHOD 1 - basic for-loop
start = time.time()
for _ in range(1000):
    results = []
    for d in l:
        if d['price'] == 50:
           results.append(d)
end = time.time()
print("Method 1 found {} item in {:f} seconds. (basic for-loop)".format(len(results), (end - start)))

#METHOD 2 - list comp with if statement
start = time.time()
results = []
for _ in range(1000):
    results = []
    results = [d for d in l if d['price'] == 50]
end = time.time()
print("Method 2 found {} item in {:f} seconds. (list comprehension)".format(len(results), (end - start)))

#METHOD 3 - using filter and a lambda expression
start = time.time()
results = []
for _ in range(1000):
    results = []
    results = list(filter(lambda d: d['price'] == 50, l))
end = time.time()
print("Method 3 found {} item in {:f} seconds. (built in filter function)".format(len(results), (end - start)))

#METHOD 4 - list comp over generator expression
start = time.time()
results = []
once = True
for _ in range(1000):
    results = []
    genResults = (d for d in l if d['price'] == 50)
    results = [it for it in genResults]
end = time.time()
print("Method 4 found {} item in {:f} seconds. (list comprehension over a generator expression)".format(len(results), (end - start)))
```

Comment: If someone with the latest version of Python 3 runs the code then please let me know if the results you get are comparable to my version.